# Converting a dataframe with metadata columns to a corpus using tm in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, tm, corpus

Issue with converting data frame to corpus

Hello, I have a df with 4 columns (1 is the text and the other three are some additional info).
I would like to convert the df into a corpus so that text from each row is a document and the corresponding info in the same row different columns are meta data.
The columns are:

```
reviews  overall_grades  ambiance_grades  identifier
```

```
structure(list(reviews = c("Amazing food, I'm personally not vegan (although I'm pro vegan) but this is the second time I go to Alter and it does feel like a treat every time! Highly recommend, vegan or not, it's amazing", "One of the best vegan menus in London. Pizza dough is to die for!", "The food was incredible with a variety of flavours! I'll definitely be coming back when I'm in town.", "Fantastic! Will come again and recommend to friends.", "Hard to find the door to the building, hard to find the restaurant. They only mix cocktails on their menu, no classics. Food delicious, service great, a little pricey."), overall_grades = c("5", "5", "5", "5", "3"), ambiance_grades = c("5", "5", "5", "5", "3"), identifier = c("Alter", "Alter", "Alter", "Alter", "Alter")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```